# How can I get basic statistics about a series of list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I would like to get the basic stats about it like the number of unique values, number of occurrence for each values. Something like [`df.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html).

My issue is that some columns have lists, and I get this error :

```
>>> df["col_a"].nunique()
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

my column looks like this:

```
col_a:
["a","b"]
["b","a"]
["c"]
["a","b","c"]
[]
NaN
```

What is the simplest way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform to tuples, which are hashable:

```
df['col_a'] = df['col_a'].dropna().apply(tuple)
```

Output:

```
       col_a
0     (a, b)
1     (b, a)
2       (c,)
3  (a, b, c)
4         ()
5        NaN
```

You can now do this (returns `5`):

```
df['col_a'].nunique()
```